# dependency validation based on dropdown selecion in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a dropdropdown list have values `Yes, No`. If you select `yes` I have validate next two textboxes. How can I do dependency validation based on dropdown selection?

```
public class MeetingAbstract
    {
        public string HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereLabel { get; set; }
        public string HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereOptions { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText { get; set; }


        public string DtPublishedTimeId { get; set; }
        public string DtPublishedTimeLabel { get; set; }
        //validate this based on HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText =Yes value
        public string DtPublishedTimeText { get; set; }


        public string PublishedPlaceId { get; set; }
        public string PublishedPlaceLabel { get; set; }
 //validate this based on HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText =Yes value

        public string PublishedPlaceText { get; set; }

 }
```

### view

```
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
   <div class="col-md-10">
     <div class="col-md-6">@Html.Label(Model.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereLabel, 
         new {@class = "control-label mandatory"})</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          @{
             options = Model.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereOptions;
             optionsList = options.Split(',').ToList();
             optionSelect = optionsList.Select(option => new SelectListItem() 
                {Text = option, Value = option}).ToList();
            }
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText,
                optionSelect, i18n_Models_Abstract.SelectOption, new { @class = "input-
                validation-error form-control" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText, 
                i18n_Models_Abstract.RequiredField, 
                new { style = "padding-left: 5px" })

         </div>
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
   <div class="col-md-10">
     <div class="col-md-6">@Html.Label(Model.DtPublishedTimeLabel, new {@class =
                    "control-label mandatory"})</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DtPublishedTimeText, new \
                  {@class = "form-control", @placeholder = Model.DtPublishedTimeLabel, 
                  required = "required", maxlength = 40})
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DtPublishedTimeText, 
        i18n_Models_Abstract.RequiredField, new { style = "padding-left: 5px" })</div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-6">@Html.Label(Model.PublishedPlaceLabel, new {@class = 
             "control-label mandatory"})</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PublishedPlaceText, new 
              {@class = "form-control", @placeholder = Model.PublishedPlaceLabel, 
              required = "required", maxlength = 40})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublishedPlaceText, 
        i18n_Models_Abstract.RequiredField, new { style = "padding-left: 5px" })
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `Validate` method on your model which will be called and exposed via `ModelState.IsValid`:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
    if (this.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText == "Yes") {
        yield return new ValidationResult("This isn't valid! Let me tell you why...");
    }
}
```

Then in your controller simply call:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    //You can only get this far if your Validate method
    //doesn't return any ValidationResult objects.
    //Do your magic!
}
```

Obviously this won't be executed client-side so if validation on the client is a requirement then you might need to roll that in.

One last note is that if you only have two values (e.g. Yes and No) a radio button may make more sense than a drop down.